# How to Redirect to component with Middleware in Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I have this structure:

```
components
    Login.vue
layouts
    default.vue
middleware
    authenticated.js
Pages
    index.vue
```

Is there somethin form that Redirect to the Login component from middleware/authenticated.js?

I have this code in default.vue, from where I do the Login.vue import.

```
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <div v-if="$auth.loggedIn" >...
      <!-- Contenido del Main -->
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <nuxt />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </div> 
    <div v-else>
      <!-- Page Login Component-->
      <Login />
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import Login from "~/components/Login"
export default {
components: {
    Login,
  },
}
</script>
```

I don't have this idea, because in the page They use it like this

```
 if (!store.state.authenticated) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
```

could someone explain to me?